# Tomcat6 session

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, single-sign-on

I'm migrating from Tomcat5.5 to Tomcat6. I have two webapps: Login and Orders.
The SSO is enabled. 
The user A logins on Login, then he browses through Orders app where some parameters are stored in session. The user A makes logout (session.invalidate()).
On the same browser (without closing it) the user B logins on Login app, then he loads Orders app and he find in session the parameters of user A! Why?

Something is changed about SSO from Tomcat5.5 and Tomcat6?

Comment: I'm using Form authentication. Seems that session.invalidate() works just for Login web-app and doesn't work for the others web-app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I forgot the <login-config> entry in the global web.xml!